# Possible correlations to institutional allocations versus market capitalization

Tags: data, indicator, anomalies

I seem to remember someone telling me a while back that a good indicator of future equity performance was how "institutionally under-owned" a given equity is versus its weight in a given broad market index (e.g., Russell 3000).

I cannot seem to remember the terms he used, but I do remember he cited academic research as supporting this premise.

I cannot find very much literature on this topic and/or data to support the claim.

Can anyone point me to a paper or resource on this potential market anomaly?

Comment: google "Institutional Ownership and Stock Returns" and similar keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that what I was looking is referred to as "Active Share".

According to [ActiveShare.info](https://activeshare.info):

> Active Share is the percentage of fund holdings that is different from
>   the benchmark holdings...
>
> Active Share is not a measure of skill but rather measures how
>   different the fund's holdings are relative to the holdings of the
>   particular benchmark considered...
>
> Research has shown that as a group and over fairly long periods of
>   time:
>
> - funds with low Active Shares have tended to underperform their    benchmarks net of costs
> - funds with high Active Shares have tended to    outperform their benchmarks net of costs, especially among funds that    do not trade
>     frequently, among small cap funds and among funds that do not have
>     very large assets under management (see further the section 'Active
>     Share Research')
>
> ...The papers below, co-authored by Martijn Cremers,
>   provide further background and explanation. For more information on
>   his academic research on Active Share, see activeshare.nd.edu.

The website also offers a search tool to determine a given fund's active share versus the S&P 500.